# F# Calling inline function with type variables

Tags: generics, f#, functional-programming, type-variables

I was trying to define a more general case for the (!) operator as follows,

```
let inline (!) (cell : ^a) =
    (^a : (member Value : ^b) cell)
```

So that it not only works for `ref` type, but any type with a `Value` member.

```
> !(ref 10) ;;
val it : int = 10

> !(lazy 5) ;;
val it : int = 5
```

But problem arises when I try to apply it to a type with type variables,

```
> let getValue (c : 'a ref) = !c ;;

  let getValue (c : 'a ref) = !c ;;
  ------------------^^

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\stdin(6,19): warning FS0064: This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'a has been constrained to be type 'obj'.

val getValue : c:obj ref -> obj
```

while it works fine if I expand the inline function.

```
> let getValue (c : 'a ref) = c.Value ;;

val getValue : c:'a ref -> 'a
```

Anyone knows why this happens? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `getValue` function is not inline, the constraints won't work.

The problem is that the .NET type system can't store the type of constraints that F# can use in `inline`.

As a result, when you have a non-inline function which uses an inline function in this way, you get an error.

Comment: The latter version of `getValue` is only a manual expansion of the former version though, I know I might be missing something here but I still can't see how the former introduces more type constraints than the latter that .NET can't capture.

Comment: I think that the constraints on `getValue` are a superset of the constraints on `!`.  As smoe of the constraints on `getValue` require inline, it can't be a non-inline function